# Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null, google maps api js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to initialize load map on page click, but I have error. On my page can be more that one map, and thats why i do initialization on page click. This is my code. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
$('.button-expand').on('click', function() {
            var self = $(this).text();
            if (self === 'EXPAND') {
                var location = @item.Latitude;
                if (location != null) {
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(@item.Latitude, @item.Longitude);

                    var mapOptions = {
                        center: latlng,
                        zoom: 17,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                    var name = '#gmap-' + @item.Id;
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(name), mapOptions);

                    // create a marker
                    var image = '../Content/Images/map_icon.png';
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map,
                        icon: image
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

This is div:

```
@if (item.Latitude != null)
{
    <p>Map:</p>
    <div class="map-margin" id="gmap-@item.Id" data-id="@item.Id" style="min-height: 270px; height: 270px; min-width: 470px; width: 470px"></div>
}
```